# Converting bits in an array to a decimal number

Tags: c

I need a function (in the C language) which can convert the binary contents of an array, in this case `myArray[8] {*MSB* 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 *LSB*}` into the decimal equivalent = 255.

Any ideas on how to solve this, as efficiently as possible, as it is being done on a microcontroller?

Comment: What have you tried? How was that insufficient? In general, Stack Overflow is good at helping with problems of the form "I tried doing X, but discovered problems with this approach", while questions of the form "I need (...)" are generally frowned upon :)

Comment: You could have shown which way round the array is organised, with an example other than `255`.

Comment: Yes, I realize that i could have asked this question in a lot of better ways - i'm sorry :-) I'm new to this forum, and needed a quick answer - mostly for inspiration. I've tried several code examples from different sites with no luck - and i'm still having trouble implementing the solutions from this thread. I might have to correct a few bugs in my own code, even though i've been doing so for the last few hours. I'll do better next time :-)

Answer (score 4):

Using bitwise shifting

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    char myArray[8] = {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1};
    int i;
    int result = 0;
    for (i=0; i<sizeof(myArray); i++){
        result += myArray[sizeof(myArray)-i-1] << i;
    }
    printf("%d\n", result);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Using `signed` variables will be *undefined behaviour*. You must not shift into the sign bit.

Comment: This shifts the later elements more. You need to have myarray[0] shifted the most. Your solution has the result reversed.

Comment: @sabbahillel The OP did not specify if LSB or MSB

Comment: @WeatherVane Signed left shift of a non-negative value is defined as long as it is representable. In this case it is.

Comment: @2501 yes in this case, but when the day comes, the bad practice is already instilled. When shifting 16 bits into a 16-bit `signed int`

Comment: @WeatherVane Strawman. You said it is undefined, I corrected you. End of story.

Answer (score 2):

One solution is to add and shift in a [Horner scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horner's_method).

```
result = (...((myArray[0])<<1 + myArray[1])<< 1+ ... ) << 1 ... ) + myArray[8];
```

or in multiple expressions:

```
result = myArray[0];
result <<= 1;
result += myArray[1];
result <<= 1;
...
result += myArray[8];
```

This solution is for [MSB.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_significant_bit)

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int a[8] = {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1}; 
    int n=8,dec=0; 
    int j=0,f;

    for(int i=(n-1);i>=0;i--) 
    {
        dec=(a[i]*(int)pow(2,j))+dec;
        j++;
    }
    printf("The converted Decimal number is:  %d",dec);
   return 0;
}
```

Output: The converted Decimal number is:  255
The result is also available at: http://ideone.com/NQK0Il

Comment: He's using a micocontroller, so you shouldn't suggest a solution which needlessly uses float numbers.

Comment: @Lundin can you just tell me where you found `float` numbers?

Comment: @JafferWilson The `pow` operation returns double which need to be converted back to an integer

Comment: @JafferWilson I haven't down voted your post, nor should someone edit your post to change the meaning of the code. It still has the same issue though: you are using float numbers. Casting the result of `pow` to int doesn't change the behavior of the function, so you didn't understand my original comment. For this code to work, you will have to link a floating point library, which is not something you want on microcontroller applications. Also, the average MCU does not have a FPU so this code will be incredibly ineffective.

Comment: Replacing `pow(2,j)` with e.g. `(1<<j)` would solve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

set up the for loop

```
unsigned int result = myarray[0];
for (int i = 1; i < 8, i++);
{
    result <<= 1;
    result += myarray[i];
}
```